# Adjustable div sizes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have `div` within which I have a slideshow of images with `JQuery Cycle plugin` applied to it. The `div` looks like this

```
    <body>
    <div id="general" style="margin: auto; text-align: center">
        <div id="nav"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="prev_anchor">
            <a id="prev" href="#"><img class="arrows" src="images/left_arrow.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/bridge.jpg" /> <img src="images/club.jpg" /> <img
                    src="images/extreme.jpg" /> <img src="images/haygroup.jpg" /> <img
                    src="images/media_pro.jpg" /> <img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/resizer.jpg" /> <img src="images/thumbnail.jpg" />
                <img src="images/writingmanisfesto.jpg" /> <img
                    src="images/reactor.jpg" /> <img src="images/resizer.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/bridge.jpg" /> <img src="images/club.jpg" /> <img
                    src="images/writingmanisfesto.jpg" /> <img
                    src="images/reactor.jpg" /> <img src="images/media_pro.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="next_anchor">
            <a id="next" href="#"><img class="arrows" src="images/right_arrow.png" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
        aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> </body>
```

Now in the first set of images, there are 6 images. In the following sets there are only 5 or even less.
The image sizes are always the same.
The Css for the above code is:

```
.slideshow { 
    margin: 20px auto; 
    padding: 0; 
    float: left;
    width: 91%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.slide { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img { 
    padding: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background-color: #eee; 
    margin: 0;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
}
```

Well I tried the other property `flex` (below is the code) but still in vain.

```
.slideshow { 
    margin: 20px auto; 
    padding: 0; 
    order: 2;
    flex: 94%;
    /* float: left;
    width: 803px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto; */
}
.slide { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    /* height: 158px; */
}
.slideshow img { 
    padding: 15px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background-color: #eee; 
    margin: 0 
}
#prev_anchor {
    order: 1;
}
#next_anchor {
    order: 3
}
#prev_anchor, #next_anchor {
    /* float: left; */
    flex: 3%;
}
#wrap {
    display: flex;
    width: 67.6%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
p {
    clear: both;
}
```

While displaying the 5 set images there is no problem.
But displaying the 6 images is creating trouble. I desire that the 6th image should fall below the 5 images, which is happening exactly but the div isn't growing accordingly.

Please help me find out the mistake in my code.

Comment: it would be great if you can create a fiddle for same..

Comment: What do you mean by `div` isn't growing accordingly ?

Comment: @NikhilPatel while displaying the 6th image, there is not enough space on the side, so the 6th image falls below the 5 images. That is what I want but the 6th image isn't displayed completely. It is half hidden because the `div` doesn't readjust.

Comment: Its looking fine on my end. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/niks999/RTJEd/). This might be due to parent `div`'s. Can you give complete HTML ?

Comment: I have heard that we can make use of `display: box` or `display: flex-box`. But I don't know how or where to use in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` does not work when the parent dosent have `height` attribuute ,instead use `min-height:125px` for your `.slide` .

Comment: Neither `min-height` nor `height` works well. Could be some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

keep height of both  `.slide` and `img` `100%` or keep them to some fixed/variable value .. but make sure both are same